# PHP Codeigniter - ftp_nlist(): Unable to create temporary file. Check permissions in temporary files directory

Tags: php, codeigniter, ftp

I'm trying to display the files from my FTP server. But before that I'm checking if the folder location exists. If not, I'll create this directory. I was able to create a folder but in my page, an error occur.

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: ftp_nlist(): Unable to create temporary file. Check permissions in temporary files directory.
>
> Filename: libraries/Ftp.php
>
> Line Number: 551
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/mr-janus/application/controllers/Pages.php
>   Line: 41
>   Function: list_files
>
> File: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/mr-janus/index.php
>   Line: 315
>   Function: require_once

This is my code block:

```
$data['category'] = $this->uri->segment(2);

$config['hostname'] = 'myftp.server.com';
$config['username'] = 'username';
$config['password'] = 'password';
$path = '/files/' . $data['category'] . '/';
$connected = $this->ftp->connect($config);

if($connected){

  $files = $this->ftp->list_files($path);
  if($files == FALSE){
    $this->ftp->mkdir($path, 0777);
    $files = $this->ftp->list_files($path);
    $this->ftp->chmod('/public_html/foo/bar/', 0775);
    $this->ftp->close();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Unable to create temporary file. Check permissions in temporary files directory.

That means PHP temporary directory does not exist or the local account that runs PHP does not have a write access to the directory.

The temporary directory is set by [`sys_temp_dir` directive in `php.ini`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php).

If the directive is not set, PHP will fall back to system temporary folder.

Basically, your problem has nothing to do with your FTP code, but with your PHP configuration.