# ftp_nlist(): Unable to create temporary file. Check permissions in temporary files directory

Tags: php, ftp

I am getting this following error when trying to get ftp

> ftp_nlist(): Unable to create temporary file.  Check permissions in temporary files directory.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46316758/php-codeigniter-ftp-nlist-unable-to-create-temporary-file-check-permission

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Codeigniter - ftp\_nlist(): Unable to create temporary file. Check permissions in temporary files directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46316758/php-codeigniter-ftp-nlist-unable-to-create-temporary-file-check-permission)

Answer (score 0):

Unable to create temporary file. Check permissions in temporary files directory.

That means PHP temporary directory does not exist or the local account that runs PHP does not have a write access to the directory.

The temporary directory is set by [sys_temp_dir directive in php.ini](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php)

If the directive is not set, PHP will fall back to system temporary folder.

Basically, your problem has nothing to do with your FTP code, but with your PHP configuration.

Comment: Hi jubair

i have set the  sys_temp_dir = "E:\xampp\php\tmp" in php.ini file but still i am getting the following error can you suggest me on this

Answer (score -1):

By default php-cgi is using /tmp for creating temp file.
`Open /mnt/sdcard/droidphp/conf/php.ini and set sys_temp_dir to /data/data/org.opendroidphp/tmp/

allow_url_include = Off
default_socket_timeout = 60
sys_temp_dir = "/data/data/org.opendroidphp/tmp"`

Comment: Hi david

i also tried the following steps but still i cannot able to resolve it.

Comment: Hi RajaRajan, It worked for me. I will get back to you if I find other solutions.